# swift 3 firebase current user query

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase i'm trying to retrive current user info, which is username, photo, etc.

Here is the code:

```
let queryRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")


    queryRef.child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        print(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)
    })
```

> Here is output

{

```
email = "2@2.2";

gender = male;

nickname = "Sam <3";

username = sam;

uid = 4nyyBF91JhSLY0DhkjfJ0DCDZK03;

urlToImage = "https://firebasestorage...;
```

}

---

And how can i print something specific like getting email, username, nickname as String, And photo as uiimage?

Comment: Are you sure this is only code that you are having because the output that you are showing after the dictionary is coming from some other `print` statement.

Comment: @NiravD Oh yah sorry it was other code in other func i did it days ago. And how can i print each info like username, gender etc?

Comment: Check my solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to simply use `subscript` with your `Dictionary`. Also in Swift use `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`.

```
let queryRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
queryRef.child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
        let email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""
        print(email)
        let gender = dictionary["gender"] as? String ?? ""
        print(gender)
        //Access the other key same way.
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also i did like this "print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username"))", It will print Snap (username) sam, But i don't know if i can get that value to label. But your code works perfect thanks again!

Comment: @Sam Welcome mate :)